# The silent room

Tags: visual

So I saw this technique used in a puzzle game. Check it out here, [cipher](http://gamemastertips.com/cipher/cipher.htm).

You are a kid in a puzzle room.

You open the door, walk into the room, and close the door.

Suddenly everything goes silent. You cannot even hear your own footsteps.

On the other side, there is a door, which has a 36 character keypad, and 6 character spots. On the top of the door, you see this.

[image: goodluck]

**What should you type?**

Hints may or may not be provided.

NOTE: this is not no-computer. You have a phone in your pocket.

SECOND NOTE: the second one actually has the last stick crossing over the 3rd and 4th sticks. But since that one is identical with the 3rd one, I chose not to portray it as such.

Hint:

> What else has 5 digits? >:)

Comment: Where is the question/puzzle?

Comment: I can see the image, but not any _related_ question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is [fvta ynathntr](http://rot13.com), but can't really unambiguously decode all of the shapes.

Comment: Could be sign language

Comment: @prog_SAHIL then why dont you try it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that you should type:

> **ANSWER**
>
>  (I have revised my first guess, which was ANSN68, because a real word is a more probable answer. The R is a better fit than the 8 I had before, but the E and especially the W are speculative.)

Jmoriarty has already found out ...

> ... that the "sticks" represent fingers and that the thumb is the rightmost digit.

The keypad ...

> ... has 36 keys. The keys are not further specified, but 36 suggests that they are the 26 letters of the English alphabet and the ten decimal digits.
>
>  The connection between the keys and the arranged fingers could be a manual alphabet as used for sign language. There are many such alphabets, but let's use the [American one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_manual_alphabet).
>
>  Then **A** is a fist held up with the thumb next to it and sticking a bit out. **N** is a fist with the thumb tucked in between the middle and ring fingers. **S** is a fist with the thumb crossed over the fingertips. The index and ring fingers pointing down seems to be a less formal variant sign for N, but I've chosen to make it **W**, so that I shoehorn it into my answer. All fingers straight except the pinkie and thunb looks like 6, but with a bit of imagination coule be **E**. The **R** is represented by crossing index and middle finger and folding the thumb to cover the two bent fingers.

Or, a bit more graphically:

> [image: ![sticks interpretes as sign language]

There are some uncertainties, though:

> Some of the signs don't really match. The OP has noted that the N is supposed look like the third symbol, but it would end up looking more like ANNWER or ASSWER.

The title ...

> ... refers to the fact that sign language is used by people who cannot hear or speak. It is a silent way to communicate.

Comment: I knew it was sign language but was hurrying to school, so couldnt try it

Comment: Hmmm. Now that I look at my proposed answer I think it should be ANSWER, but I can't quite see how it works.

Comment: WAIT Its because it goes from only left to right, not up to down left to right

Answer (score 1):

So, presumably these images are

> Hands holding up fingers (digits). Let's say left-hands for argument's sake.

If in every image, the right-most line is

> The thumb

Then when it is horizontal it is

> Tucked into the palm

And when it crosses other lines it is

> Holding those fingers down

Then reading from left to right we see

1.

> Only the thumb held out (back of hand)

2.

> The thumb, index, and middle fingers held out, but upside-down (front of hand)

3.

> The pinky and ring fingers held out (back of hand)

4.

> All five digits held out (back of hand)

5.

> Fours fingers held out, with the thumb tucked into the palm (back of hand)

6.

> Not 100% on this, maybe upside-down with thumb holding down index fingerand ring and middle fingers crossed??? (front of hand)

This would give us

> 1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 3

Comment: No, you're interpreting the hands wrong.